# Strophe js in Titanium Appcelerator?

Tags: titanium, xmpp, titanium-mobile, ejabberd, strophe

I want to create a chat application in Titanium appcelerator using Strophe.js library. I have gone through [strophe js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/) libraries and their documents as well. I believe  we can use strophe.js to build xmpp based chat app in web.

Thanks in advance, Can anyone please clarify the following doubts,

- Is it possible to use strophe js inside our Titanium Appcelerator,If yes please suggest me how to use it. I tried to include the strophe js inside the titanium it shows **can't find module error**

Here's the code i tried with.

```
Ti.include("includes/strophe.js");
Ti.include("includes/strophe.register.js");
connection.register.connect("localhost:5280", callback, wait, hold);
var callback = function (status) {
    if (status === Strophe.Status.REGISTER) {
        connection.register.fields.username = "newuser";
        connection.register.fields.password = "123456";
        connection.register.submit();
    } else if (status ===  Strophe.Status.REGISTERED) {
        console.log("registered!");
        connection.authenticate();
    } else if (status ===  Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
        console.log("logged in!");
    } else {
        // every other status a connection.connect would receive
    }
};
$.index.open();
```

- Can you please suggest to use any other libraries that can be used inside the Titanium Appceleartor to build chat application using **XMPP**

Comment: Could you provide code example presenting how have you tried to include strophe.js inside Titanium?

Comment: Thanks for your response @daniula. I updated the code that i tried to register a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Strophe is created to be used inside browser and modifying it to work inside Titanium is rather risky.

The only XMPP module for Titanium, which I could find is [titanium-xmpp on GitHub](https://github.com/jmartin82/titanium-xmpp/tree/master/Resources/xmpp).

Comment: Thanks for your clarification again @daniula. I also tried with that example that module shows an error. if you worked with that module can u please give a suggestion to clear the following error------------






[ERROR] :  Script Error Couldn't find module: JXMPPJID
[ERROR] :  Script Error Module "xmpp/JXMPP" failed to leave a valid exports object

Comment: Did you try to clone whole repository and build it example app?

Comment: yes, i downloaded that project and imported that as an existing titanium project.

Comment: Hey daniula, did you have any success on that? Thanks!

Comment: @CarlosHenriqueLustosa Nope